# The name of the design I came with using diodes

Tags: diodes

Have designed those diodes to make 12volts cause I was having only 7volts, I came with it to boost up the bolts but I forgot of the term to describe my design. 
[image]

Comment: Looks like a standard bridge rectifier configuration to me - and it doesn't 'boost' anything.

Comment: Is that it? You're saying that if I put 7v into _that_, I'll get 12v out?

Comment: @KingDuken - if you add an extra helping of magic smoke maybe ...

Comment: It's a simple [diode *bridge*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode_bridge)

Comment: I recalled. It's a standard bridge rectifier. Thanks for the contribution

Answer (score 5):

You've made a bridge rectifier.

If you put a sinusoidal 7 V RMS into the bridge rectifier and add a smoothing capacitor to the DC then you'll get about 12 V DC. The RMS voltage of a sinewave is \$ \frac {1}{\sqrt 2} V_{pk} \$ so the peak voltage in your case will be \$ 7 \sqrt 2 = 9.9 \ \text V\$. From this we must take away two diode voltage drops (0.7 V each) resulting with an output voltage of 8.5 V. Adding a load will cause further droop in voltage.

You won't get 12 V DC with only 7 V RMS in.

[image]

*Figure 1. A full-wave DC bridge rectifier with smoothing capacitor. Image source: [Electronic Tutorials](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode_6.html).*